# How to disable inner-outline on selected table cell in Firefox

Tags: firefox, click, cell, inline

Using Firefox on OSX when I cmd+click on a table cell I get an blue inner outline.
 I searched for a way to disable this behavior on my web application but didn't found anything.
 I tried to capture the onclick or set the CSS outline to 0px to no avail.
 I also looked at MDC Mozilla CSS extension but many are undocumented.

Is there a way to remove this inner outlinein a given HTML doc?

Answer (score 2):

You must set CSS property -moz-user-select to none of the container table element.

> table {
>       -moz-user-select: none;
>   }

This will not only disable cell selection but will also unable you to select text inside the table.

Comment: Would be nice to keep the text selection possibility :/